# Can I create socket between two devices where one device is connected to wifi internet and other is connected to 3G or 2G internet.?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

Can I create socket between two devices where one device is connected to wifi internet and other is connected to 3G or 2G internet. Or both devices are connected to 3G or 2G.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, I have an android device on which Socketserver is running and now I'm using another android device to make connection to that socketserver. Code is working fine if my both devices are in the same network over wifi but if one device (on which server is running) is on 3G and other is on wifi then I'm getting error: "connection timeout". Public IP address I'm entering manually.

Answer (score 0):

WHY do you do that?
you can create a socketServer at PC side.
And all android apps can create socket to connect  the SocketServer.
whatever you use wifi or 2G,3G.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, I have an android device on which Socketserver is running and now I'm using another android device to make connection to that socketserver. Code is working fine if my both devices are in the same network over wifi but if one device (on which server is running) is on 3G and other is on wifi then I'm getting error: "connection timeout". Public IP address I'm entering manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create socket,
Socket creation takes two paramter a valid IP address and a port Number to establish connection.

i.e socket= new socket(IPAddress,Port) it depends upon just a route to resolve the IPAddress where port should be available to listen.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, I have an android device on which Socketserver is running and now I'm using another android device to make connection to that socketserver. Code is working fine if my both devices are in the same network over wifi but if one device (on which server is running) is on 3G and other is on wifi then I'm getting error: "connection timeout". Public IP address I'm entering manually.